# What's the internal state size and output range of mrg32k3a?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

This is Pierre L'Ecuyer's PRNG.  [I know its period is $2^{191}$](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/streams00.pdf), but I don't know what is its internal state size.  What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is based on the given period construction from your link.

You have to store the two modulus

- $m_1 = 2^{32} − 209 = 4294967087$ and
- $m_2 = 2^{32} − 22853 = 4294944443,$

and the internal states are;

- $s_{1,n} = \{x_{1,n},x_{1,n+1}, x_{1,n+1} \}$ and
- $s_{2,n} = \{x_{2,n},x_{2,n+1}, x_{2,n+1} \}$.

The $z_n = (x_{1,n}- x_{2,n}) \bmod m_1$, evolves with this $x_{1,n}$ and $x_{2,n}$ where each requrrence relation for  $x_{1,n}$ and $x_{2,n}$ is taken module $m_1$ and $m_2$, respectively;

$$x_{1,n} = (1403580 \times x_{1,n-2} - 810728 \times x_{1,n-3} ) \bmod m_1,$$
$$x_{2,n} = (527612 \times x_{2,n-2} -1370589 \times x_{2,n-3} ) \bmod m_2$$

Therefore you need to store 3 moduli $m_1$ and 3 moduli $m_2$ internal states.

The $m_1$ and $m_2$ is very close to $2^{32}$, so we can say that you need;

- 6 unsigned 32-bit integers for the internal states.
- For the modulus, you will also need 2 unsigned 32-bit integers.

the range is $m_1$ since the $z_n$ is taken $\mod m_1$.

**Yes**; the state for all practical purposes is $8 \cdot 32=256$-bit.

Comment: So the state is - for all practical purposes - $8 \cdot 32 = 256$ bits, right?

Comment: I added the modules, too. Usually, they are not considered as states. But if you think about all the memory requirements, yes.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearly showing the steps.  Interesting question about considering or not considering the modules.  I would not consider them since they will not make anything harder on the adversary's side.